# An adjective to describe a TYPE of person who is reluctant to accept truth (when person feels substandard)

Tags: adjectives

Eg. Oh I'm glad I'm not in a relationship (because you have issues with yours) -yet the person actually wants to be in one.

eg. I'm glad I don't have a nice car (because you have to pay for premium gas) -yet the person actually likes nice cars.

I'm not looking for :jealousy, envy, something towards lacking confidence...

Comment: Can you say what the word is in your native language, or explain why you suppose that there is a single word for this.

Answer (score 1):

A person whose behavior is inconsistent with his claims could be described as [hypocritical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrisy).